# Probability of collison when shortening a URL

Tags: probability

Given a url shortener service that uses alphanumeric characters to represent the URL and the length of the shortened URL is $7$, is the max number of URL’s that can be stored before collisions $62^7$, and therefore the probability of a collision is $\frac1{62^7}$?

As Url's are added to the service does the probability become $\frac{1+\text{number of Url's added}}{62^7}$?

Comment: 67^7? Why not 62^7? --- The general formula (numberOfUrlsAdded / totalAmount) seems correct. The "1 + " seems wrong.

Comment: The rule of thumb with the birthday paradox is that you are more likely than not to get collisions after `sqrt(N)` items.

Comment: Yes, why 67? 26+26+10 = 62. But anyway, this is a off  topic.

Comment: @Bohemian yes it should be 62, thanks, question updated.

Answer (score 1):

26+26+10=62, not 67.

and you are searching for the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem

Comment: This is not the birthday paradoxon. The Birhtday paradoxon assigns all keys at once and asks for the probability of at least one collision. The question asks what the probability of a collision on insertion is, given that you have `n` of `m` keys (`n < m`) already taken.